# Can I create an Android Pay Gift Card for multiple merchants?

Tags: android, android-pay

Is it possible to have a gift card which is accepted by multiple merchants in Android Pay? The scenario I'm looking at is a gift card accepted across merchants in a shopping mall.

The documentation would suggest vouchers and cards are tied to an individual merchant.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"You can store digital copies of your loyalty, reward, membership, gift cards, and special offers (like coupons, promotions, and discounts) for thousands of merchants in Android Pay."

- https://support.google.com/androidpay/answer/6289384?hl=en

You can store cards, but it would be hard to create a new one.

VISA or MASTERCARD gift cards would do the job...

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Yes, you can store copies of cards for thousands of merchants, but from what I've read, each of those cards is unique to an individual merchant. Is there a way to have a single card cater for multiple merchants?